# .net core custom model binding

Tags: asp.net-core-mvc, model-binding

I have a model such as

```
public class MyModel
{
  public MyObject myObject {get;set;}
}

public class MyObject
{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
}
```

With out using a custom model binder everything works great. I am trying to implement a model binder and not getting anywhere -- the resources that I have come from are
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qDRORgoZxZU (returns null model to the controller)

http://intellitect.com/custom-model-binding-in-asp-net-core-1-0/ (controller dies on the constructor)

http://hotzblog.com/asp-net-vnext-defaultmodelbinder-and-automatic-viewmodel-string-trim/ (can not even find MutableObjectModelBinder in the .net-core namespace)

Ideally what I want is to track which properties where set by the ModelBinder.

```
public class MyObject
{
  public string FirstName {get;set;}
  public string LastName {get;set;}
  public List<String> ModifiedProperties {get;set;}
}
```

when the object is created by the ModelBinder for each property that is being set it adds it to the ModifiedProperties list.

Comment: My first big mistake is that I tried to trigger the ModelBinder on MyModel. The ModelBinder should be triggered on the FirstName, LastName property. This is done by checking the context.Metadata.ContainerType

Comment: Did you ever get this sorted? Any chance of some sample code? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

This is solution. You need to implement IModelBinderProvider and IModelBinder

```
public class EntityFrameworkModelBinderProvider : IModelBinderProvider
{    
  public IModelBinder GetBinder(ModelBinderProviderContext context)
  {       
    //We only want to invoke the CustomeBinder on IBaseEntity classes
    if (context.Metadata.ContainerType != null && context.Metadata.ContainerType.GetInterfaces().Contains(typeof(SurgeOne.Core.IBaseEntity)))
    {
    //We only create the custom binder on value types. E.g. string, guid, etc
    if (context.Metadata.ModelType.GetTypeInfo().IsValueType ||
        context.Metadata.ModelType == typeof(System.String))
    {
      return new EntityFrameworkModelBinder();
    }        
  }
  return null;        
}
```

}

And IModelBinder

```
public class EntityFrameworkModelBinder : IModelBinder
{
  public Task BindModelAsync(ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
  {
    if (bindingContext == null)
    {
      throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(bindingContext));
    }

    //Get the value
    var valueProviderResult = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
    if (valueProviderResult == ValueProviderResult.None)
    {
      // no entry
      return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    //Set the value -- not sure what this does
    bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, valueProviderResult);

    //Set the value -- this has to match the property type.
    System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter typeConverter = System.ComponentModel.TypeDescriptor.GetConverter(bindingContext.ModelType);
    object propValue = typeConverter.ConvertFromString(valueProviderResult.FirstValue);
    bindingContext.Result = ModelBindingResult.Success(propValue);

    //Code to track changes. 

    return Task.CompletedTask;
  } //BindModelAsync
}
```